# Where is the lookup transform applied?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

This is about the SSIS lookup transform.

Does the lookup transform pull the source data into the ETL server and then apply to lookup transform OR does the filtering happen at the source server?

Answer (score 8):

By default, the lookup Transformation will use the table/query defined in it and in the pre-execute state for the data flow, it will execute that query and cache the results within local memory. This default behaviour is the full cache option.

The other two options are None and Partial. None will result in a query being executed against the source system for each source row received. Partial, in optimal configuration, will result in a query being executed against the source system for each new row from the source row received. Otherwise, it'll use a cached copy of the lookup row. I say optimal as there is a max memory configuration value that could result in the oldest row being evicted prior to second consumption and thus, a query is fired again.

Given your other questions and assuming Full cache configuration - the pre-execute process will run a query to generate your set of users and cache that list. Then, ALL of the data from your OLTP Sales system will be pulled into the data pipeline. Each row will be evaluated against the cached list of users for equality and if a match is found, the source row will flow to the Matched output. Unmatched rows will error, flow to the Unmatched output, or continue into the Matched output depending on the match options you specify (Error, to Unmatched, Ignore).

Comment: This question has got lot of down votes. Please can you delete the answer so that I can delete this question.

Comment: The help centers offers guidance on [when it's appropriate to delete questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) I would encourage you to review the [vote down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) section of the help center as well and try to identify whether your questions meet the criteria of "When should I vote down?" Or to focus on the positive, [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and see what you can do to improve the original request.